# Is putting static methods in interfaces a good practice?

Tags: java, methods, interface, static

Let's say I have a method `getAverageDifficulty` in my class `Difficulty` that goes like this:

```
public static Float getAverageDifficulty (List<Difficulty> difficultyList) {

    ...
    return average;

}
```

My method obviously needs to be static, since it makes no sense requiring an instance of `Difficulty`. Now let's say I'm using an interface `IDifficulty` so I can change my implementation later. Obviously, I do want my `getAverageDifficulty` method to be available from `IDifficulty`, and, as I can't declare a static method abstract, the obvious option is to put `getAverageDifficulty` directly in my interface. My question is: am I making a mistake by putting that static method in my interface, which contains other `Difficulty` methods waiting to be implemented? Should I not mix static and "normal" interface abstract methods? Should I create `DifficultyHelper` class and put my method there?

Comment: You can just use stream to get average

Comment: I would put it in a utils or helper class.  It doesn't make sense to put it in your Difficulty interface since it isn't reliant on Difficulty. Essentially if you're going to call it any place that isn't Difficult it doesn't make sense to have it there

Comment: There is no such thing as good practice. There is only what is best in a given situation, and there may be multiple answers to that, all equally good.

Comment: Matthew I mean, it is kinda relying on difficulty since it takes a list of Difficulty as a param

Comment: I would use a helper class.  A way to think about this is that the method is providing behavior which want to attach to the type 'List<Difficulty>', except that type is not explicitly available.  (As an aside: the parameter type should perhaps be 'Collection<? extends Difficulty>'.)  Note that the sample method is of a different character than a default method on an interface.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, thanks for the answer!

Comment: no reason the helper class can't be an interface. saves you from writing a private constructor that code coverage flags as uncovered.

Comment: I'm not a coverage maniac so that's not too problematic for me, and I kinda prefer interfaces to only have non implemented methods, but ty for your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ultimately, this is a matter of style. However, if the only purpose of the helper class is to hold this method (and maybe a few similar ones), then you will be saving yourself one class definition by placing them in the interface:

> As of Java 8, the restriction that interfaces cannot contain static methods was eliminated, so there is typically little reason to provide a noninstantiable companion class for an interface [Effective Java, 3rd edition, Item 1: Consider static factory methods instead of
> constructors].

Answer (score 0):

Static methods in interfaces are similar to the default methods except that we cannot override these methods in the classes that implements these interfaces.so in my opinion its not not necessary to write static methods in interfaces until you want to prevent overriding.

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is that my Difficulty.class is not gonna be visible in my next layer, since I'm only using interfaces so I can ensure decouplement inbetween layers, so I wouldn't be able to use that method. so I need that method either in IDifficulty.class or in a utils class